# How to fix 403 error when open wordpress element using tagdiv theme?

Tags: wordpress

Please help me. I'm trying to open Edit Content by using "Text with title" element in td-composer. But the server is not responding to me and it show 403 error.
I was try to set plugin folder and td-composer folder to 777, but not work.

[image: image about this error]
thanks for read!

I was try to change permission, Im using Nginx.

Comment: I suggest you read this article https://pimylifeup.com/chmod-777/

Comment: I was try chmod to 777 folder wp-plugin and td-composer, but not word

Comment: that article explains why you should not use 777

Comment: so do you have any idea to fix this :(

Comment: with the provided info i think is not posible to know the reason. note that 403 could be that you are not probably authorized (no matter the files permissions)

Comment: :( i still try to find out the way to fix this